# In my python quiz generator, when i test the program, it tells me my answer is wrong but it is not as i have checked by printing answer

Tags: python, computer-science

```
import random

questions = 1
score = 0

input("Please enter your name: ")

operator = ["+","-","*"]

while questions<10:
  num1 = (random.randint(0,15))
  num2 = (random.randint(0,15))
  picked_operator = random.choice(operator)
  print("What is " + str(num1) +str(picked_operator) +str(num2), "?")
  question = '{} {} {}'.format(num1, picked_operator, num2)
  answer = input()
  if answer == eval(question): 
    print("You are correct")
    score = score+1
  else:
    print("incorrect")
  questions = questions + 1  
  print(answer)
```

example of what is printed:
please enter your name:  dan
what is 11 + 3?
14
incorrect
14
what is 13-7?
................

Answer (score 0):

The error is with your `input()` statement. Use this instead:

```
answer = int(input())

# OR

if answer == str(eval(question)):
    # Do things
```

You're accepting `answer` as a string quantity, and comparing it with an integer, see below:

```
>>> 12 == '12'
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The eval function in Python returns an Integer, and the input function returns a String.
When you compare Int with Str, you will not get equal.

> `answer = int(input())`

it should be good like that